# Appropriate way to make nvm-installed versions of Node usable in Kubuntu Application Menu/Launcher?

Tags: kde, nodejs, npm

When installing node with `nvm`, it works great in the terminal - you can run node applications with `node path/to/app.js`, as you'd expect.

However, if you create an Application Menu launcher in Kubuntu/KDE, it will not work - it can't find the node binary node unless you explicitly give it the complete path, i.e. `/home/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin app.js`.  When node is installed directly (via apt rather than nvm), this is not necessary.

However, even specifying the full path does not work for npm. For example, creating a menu launcher with command `bash -c "cd /path/to/project ; /home/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/npm run script-name; read -n 1"`, the resulting terminal window shows `/usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory`  (the final `read -n 1` is just to prevent the terminal from closing right after the error).

So the question is: why can KDE's application menu not find the node/npm binaries, and more importantly, how can one create a launcher that will work with npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2025).

You just have to move the 3 lines that nvm adds to ~/.bashrc:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

into ~/.profile instead. Logout & login, and it will work.